# In runtime - Segmentation fault (core dumped) - malloc

Tags: c

```
/*Name: "Inserisci in ordine"
* Author: fra trement
* task ->
*       creates a list of integers,
*       in ascending order. 
*       Then print the list and 
*       free up the memory
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodo{
    int dato;
struct nodo*next;
}nodo_t;

typedef nodo_t*Ptr_nodo;

Ptr_nodo Insinordine(Ptr_nodo l, int num); /* Insert the value in order inside the list */
Ptr_nodo destroy(Ptr_nodo list); /* Destroy the list to free HEAP */
void stampa(Ptr_nodo l); /* Print the list */

int main(){
    Ptr_nodo head=NULL;;
    int val;
    
    printf("Lista di interi positivi; inserisci 0 per terminare\n"); /* eng-> List of positive integers; enter 0 to finish */
    do{
        printf("> ");
        scanf("%d", &val);
        if(val>0){
            head = Insinordine(head, val);
            // printf("Inserimento\n");
        } else if(val==0){
            printf("**FINE**\n"); /* eng-> **END** */
        } else {
            printf("Valore non valido!\n"); /* eng-> Value not valid */
        }
    } while (val != 0);
    if(head!=NULL){
        stampa(head);
        // printf("PRINTED\n");
        head = destroy(head);
        // printf("DISTROYED\n");
    } else {
        printf("list: -|\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


Ptr_nodo Insinordine (Ptr_nodo l, int num){
    Ptr_nodo tmp=NULL, curr=l, prec=NULL;
    int count;
    
    tmp = (Ptr_nodo)malloc(sizeof(nodo_t));
    if(tmp){
        tmp->dato = num;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if(l==NULL){
            l=tmp;
        } else {
            while(curr->dato < num && curr->next != NULL){
                prec = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            tmp->next = curr;
            prec->next = tmp;
        }
    } else printf("Errore memoria\n"); /* eng-> Memory error */
}   

Ptr_nodo destroy (Ptr_nodo list){
    Ptr_nodo tmp;
    while(list!=NULL){
        tmp = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
    return NULL;
}
    
void stampa (Ptr_nodo l){
    printf("list: ");
    while(l!=NULL){
        printf("%d -> ", l->dato);
        l = l->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Hi, Can anyone tell me where am I wrong?
The program seems to work, but as soon as I enter the second value, the error *"segmentation fault (core dumped)"* appears.
I would like to know if it is a code related error, or, is it a heap memory problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oal7q.png)
I hope everything is clear.

Comment: Check the comment above, it has the solution, no return value in ```Insinordine ```function. Also no need to return always NULL in ```destroy``` function, you can make it a void function.

Comment: why are you not returning updated `head` address from `Insinordine` ?

Comment: it was an error, I fixed it but it didn't fix the _ "segmentation fault"_ error

Comment: OT:  regarding: `typedef nodo_t*Ptr_nodo;`  it is a very poor programming practice to `typedef` pointers.  Such practice just leads to confusion

Comment: regarding: if(l==NULL)
        {
            l=tmp;
        }`  This does not insert the first node into the linked list.  All it does is modify the parameter on the stack. .  In `main()`, this statement does nothing useful because the function: `Insinordine()` fails to return the updated pointer.  Also your compiler should have told you about the missing `return ` statement. with: `untitled1.c:68:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, you code has issues with logic as well. It seems like you are trying to create a sorted linked-list, and the logic seems to be incorrect. Either way, the reason you are getting segfault is because you initialized `prev` as `NULL`, and if the `while` condition fails in the first iteration, you try to access `NULL`'s elements, which causes the segfault.

Use debugging tools like `gdb` to see what is going on. A simple check with gdb indicates the issue at `line 67` and you can try to figure out the issue from there on.

For starters, initialize `prev` as your head as well.

```
prev = l;
```

Comment: Yes, my intenction is doing a sort of list made from many nodes, each node is a struct with an integer and a pointer to the next node. I want to insert each integer > 0 in a node, and insert the node in the linked-list, but in order from the min to  the max

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of problems.

1. You are not returning the updated `head` (`l` in your case from `Insinordine` ) when you add elements to your list.
2. Your `Insinordine` function is wrong in finding the next elements based on its comparison and insertion.

I just renamed your `l` with `head`.

Go through the code below and get back in case of any clarifications, added comments inline.

```
Ptr_nodo Insinordine (Ptr_nodo head, int num){
    Ptr_nodo tmp=NULL, curr=NULL, prec=NULL;
    int count;
    
    tmp = (Ptr_nodo)malloc(sizeof(nodo_t));
    if(tmp){
        tmp->dato = num;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if(head == NULL){
            head = tmp;
            return head;
        } else {
            // first check whether head->data is less than new element (num)
            if( head->dato < num )
            {
                tmp -> next = head;
                head = tmp;
                return head;
            }
            // assign prec pointer the head 
            prec = head;
            // curr is head -> next
            curr = head -> next;
            
            // check until you reach NULL or curr->dato > num
            // there will be two outcomes of while
            while( curr && curr->dato > num ){
                prec = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            //1. if curr is NULL then we have reached the end, so add the tmp at end
            if(!curr) {
                prec->next = tmp;
                return head;
            }
            //2. curr is not NULL, but curr->dato < num
            // so, we store curr node(prec->next) in tmp->next and tmp in curr node(prec->next)
            else {
                tmp->next = prec->next;
                prec->next = tmp;
                return head;
            }
        }
    } else printf("Errore memoria\n"); /* eng-> Memory error */
}
```

Comment: All is clear, the program work.  _Thank_  _you!_